# How to lay down elements vertically from top to bottom, and then from right to left, using a clean HTML markup?

Tags: html, css

I have a few block-level (or inline-block, it doesn't matter) elements with pre-defined dimensions. I want them at the top-right portion of a container `div`. I want them being positioned one next to the other, from top to the bottom. When there isn't enough space, I want a new column at left of the previous one, also going from top to the bottom.

In other words, I want something like this:

```
.------------.
|       4  1 |
|       5  2 |
|          3 |
'------------'
```

How can I achieve it using a pure-CSS solution with a clean HTML?

Even better if it can adapt itself to the available height.

---

#### Alternative effects that I can achieve (but are not what I want):

With a combination of `column-width: <something>; column-gap: 0;`, I can achieve this effect:

```
.------------.
| 1  4       |
| 2  5       |
| 3          |
'------------'
```

With `float: right;`, I can achieve this effect:

```
.------------.
|    3  2  1 |
|       5  4 |
|            |
'------------'
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to group them in an inner `div` - e.g. a `div` around each coloumn?

Comment: A fiddle for fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zf82D/

Comment: Another fiddle for fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/6WbGD/

Comment: @Steeven: grouping into columns using HTML elements is not a "clean HTML" solution, and it won't auto-adjust to the available height. It is an interesting workaround, but not one that I want to use.

Comment: Note: maybe this effect can also be achieved using [flex (Flexible Box Layout Module)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but I haven't tried it yet. If someone wants to try, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the writing mode, you can get the columns module to do what you want:

http://tinker.io/9f846

```
ul {
    columns: 10em;
    direction: rtl;
}

li {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6WbGD/1/
Also, to whoever voted this down, can you please explain the reasons why this is not a good idea?

Comment: Browser support is better than I expected for this property:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/direction (IE5.5, Firefox 1.0, etc.)